# Text selection on Android Samsung Galaxy devices hides whole screen

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, textselection

Only `Samsung Galaxy` devices are affected (checked on `SGS4` and `SGN2`). Looks like this:

[image: Text selection hides all screen on SGS4]

Anyone had this issue before? Any ideas what could cause this? How to fix it?

Update:

This happens when double tapped on text row. If pressing `Select All` and `Copy` buttons, text is copied.